# Software to drive remote output (audio + video)

Tags: untagged

I am looking for a way to send my laptop's video and audio outputs to another machine on the network, which is itself connected to a TV and audio amplifier unit. The idea is to be able to switch to "presentation mode" wirelessly. I am using Ubuntu.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should check a VNC server.

Comment: VNC Server seems to do the opposite of what I need: Their server provides a remote desktop to their client, which initiates the connection. In my case, I want to send my own desktop to the server (or client, or whatever its name is) that displays it on its screen. So my server is like a VNC client that's continuously listening in to connections from VNC servers. Is that doable with VNC or any other remote desktop software?

Comment: Not that I know of, however it should be relatively easy to write your own script that will connect to your server with the desktop ip/port and have the "server" connect to your desktop. Also you can make the script use rdesktop if your desktop is running windows. Keep in mind you will have to `export DISPLAY` and `xhost +` on the server otherwise ssh won't be able to use X.